# Mail server is seen under different IP by other mail servers, than it has --> mail marked as spam

Tags: email, spam, gateway, proxmox

I am experiencing problems with delivering emails from my server and can't see the real cause of this problem.
Emails from my mail server are marked as spam. In message sourcecode I can see, that my mail server (85.13.75.28 - dione.hostingprome.cz) is seen under providers gateway ip (85.13.75.1). PTR record is set properly to my IP and I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what can I do to be able to deliver my customer emails i.e. to gmail. I am not blacklisted in any relevant mail blacklist server.

Some mailservers even refuses to talk to my server probably because of the same problem (my server is seen under different IP and then PTR doesn't resolve properly...)

Message "sourcecode"

```
Delivered-To: zdenekkroc@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.97.10 with SMTP id dw10csp8280oeb;
Sun, 23 Feb 2014 09:45:06 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.14.3.72 with SMTP id 48mr20284444eeg.34.1393177505989;
Sun, 23 Feb 2014 09:45:05 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <ydenda@ydenda.cz>
Received: from dione.hostingprome.cz ([85.13.75.1])
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id p44si29941170eeu.26.2014.02.23.09.45.02
for <zdenekkroc@gmail.com>
(version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
Sun, 23 Feb 2014 09:45:03 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 85.13.75.1 is neither permitted nor denied by best         guess record for domain of ydenda@ydenda.cz) client-ip=85.13.75.1;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=neutral (google.com: 85.13.75.1 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess    record   for domain of ydenda@ydenda.cz) smtp.mail=ydenda@ydenda.cz
Received: from artemis.ydenda.cz (artemis.hostingprome.cz [85.13.75.27])
by dione.hostingprome.cz (Postfix) with ESMTP id AA24A328DD
for <zdenekkroc@gmail.com>; Sun, 23 Feb 2014 18:44:32 +0100 (CET)
```

Domain ydenda.cz is for testing purposes, for other domains I can get the same result.

Here you can see partial result from traceroute command:
row 10 : providers router 
row 11 : my proxmox server (PTR record is zombie - shouldn't be problem?) 
row 12 : mail server in container

```
10  85.13.75.1 (85.13.75.1)  41.515 ms  41.577 ms  41.678 ms
11  fw.gymnaziumvodnany.cz (85.13.75.26)  41.717 ms  41.805 ms  44.067 ms
12  dione.hostingprome.cz (85.13.75.28)  44.054 ms  44.124 ms  44.140 ms
```

My email don't contain any forbidden words.

Could you please give me some clues how to get out of this situation? Or how is it possible?

Thank you for help. Zdenek

Comment: Do you have configured a ``relay_host`` on your mail server?

Comment: Are the emails spam or do they look like spam?

Comment: Talk to your provider and check if they do any form of NATing.

Comment: I agree with Jenny, they're intercepting your mail and relaying it onwards.

Comment: 85.13.75.1 doens't have a PTR record.  artemis.ydenda.cz doesn't have an A record.  And your provider is clearly routing by NAT or other means (at least mail) through 87.13.75.1

Comment: Does your provider permit you to run a mail server? This really looks like they do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single most effective thing under your control is to publish SPF records for your sending domains (ydenda.cz, and whatever others)

http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes is about everything you need to know about SPF in one page.  You would want to include 85.13.75.1, 85.13.75.28, and 85.13.75.27 as permitted senders in the example you posted.

Some misguided or overzealous mail recipients like to enforce that PTR and A/AAAA records match, there's not much you can do about that until your provider exposes your real IP (not 85.13.75.1) and gives you either a DNS delegation or a PTR that matches yours.

Out of curiosity, if you google "what's my IP" what does it return?  If it's 85.13.75.1 then your provider is probably NATing all of your outbound connections.  (In which case I'd get a cheap VPS from a largish provider and set up a VPN and mail relay.)

Comment: While I agree about SPF, if I were the sender I'd still want to check why they are NATing his mail traffic. Since ping and traceroute appear to come straight from the server, I'm guessing they're doing some kind of antispam filtering.

Comment: OK, I obviously need to talk to my provider, because he probably forgot to take me out from SNAT. That's the reason why I am having this problem. I'll also set up SPF records for my mail servers.